Cutting board rough to touch after oiling
I have a maple cutting board, it has been oiled and it’s rough. It was a homemade gift. I am not sure how it fix it. It feels very dry.
My friend that made it said they oiled it three times.

Hi, welcome to WSE. Do you have a close up picture? How rough is it? Raw lumber rough, or just slightly fuzzy? Do you know what oil was used?
